# Skip maven plugin in parent project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, cxf-codegen-plugin

I need skip plugin execution in parent pom project, but execute it in child projects. How do it this? Child projects use cxf-codegen-plugin with wsdl in path **${basedir}/src/main/resources/${wsdl-name}.wsdl**, but parent project dont'n have wsdl.

Build => plugins in parent pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/${wsdl-name}.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You move the above plugin configuration to `<pluginManagement>`. Then you add to the `<plugins>` section of your parent POM:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>generate-sources</id>
       <inherited>false</inherited>
       <phase>none</phase>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me a lot. Is there an alternative to the undocumented (not existing) "none" phase?

Comment: @FlorianWolters AFAIK this is the standard way of doing it. You could probably use any string that is not a real phase, e.g. `<phase>keinephase</phase>`.